# AS3 Garbage collection on Local Variables

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, garbage-collection

If a local variable in a function registers some event listners, is there a way to remove that event listner? Will that variable be garbage collected after the event listner fires?

Sample code:

```
Class A{

function init(){
    var _loader = new URLLoader();
    _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
}

function complete(e:Event){
//How to remove the event listner here on _loader since it is a local variable in init() and not an instance variable. 
//Will _loader be ever garbage collected?
}

}
```

If `_loader` was an instance variable, we could have referenced it in the `complete` handler function and removed the eventlistner on it, to let it garbage collected. What happens to local variables like `_loader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the currentTarget of the event object:

```
function complete(e:Event):Void {
   URLLoader(e.currentTarget).removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
}
```

Also, be careful about local variables and event listeners. In theory (saying this as I have been unable to find an official documentation about it) your loader variable will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as your function expires. Of course in most cases this does not happen right away so your listener will fire just ok. But I would still make it a class variable.

Comment: Is it required to cast e.currentTarget to the object type (URLLoader in this case) to remove the event listner?

Comment: @dev_musings I guess as Object is a dynamic class, it is not necessary to cast it, it should not raise an exception.

Comment: casting is better since it will help the compiler figuring out errors + in most editor will open code hinting. There's just nothing wrong that can come from casting and plenty of wrong that can come from not casting.